# How to get current dropzone in interact.js

Tags: javascript, interact.js

i've got  a lot of dropzone in my page that has the "dropzone" class.
I've got:

```
interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
     accept: '.draggable',
     overlap: 0.01, ...
ondrop: function (event) { ... }
```

The question is how can i know what is the current dropzone where i drop my "object" in ondrop function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
ondrop: function (event) {
  alert(event.relatedTarget.id
    + ' was dropped into '
    + event.target.id);}
```

Taken from: http://interactjs.io/docs/#drop-events